# Import into object?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Let's start with an example:

```
import renewCreepLife from '../tasks/renew_creep_life';
import harvestEnergy from '../tasks/harvest_energy';
import pickupEnergy from '../tasks/pickup_energy';
import storeEnergy from '../tasks/store_energy';
import upgradeController from '../tasks/upgrade_controller';

const taskFuncs = {
    [Tasks.RENEW]: renewCreepLife,
    [Tasks.PICKUP_ENERGY]: pickupEnergy,
    [Tasks.HARVESTING]: harvestEnergy,
    [Tasks.STORING]: storeEnergy,
    [Tasks.UPGRADING]: upgradeController,
};
```

Is there any way to simplify this so that I'm not creating these pointless temporary variable names? Something like:

```
// incorrect but desired syntax
const taskFuncs = {
    [Tasks.RENEW]: import '../tasks/renew_creep_life',
};
```

N.B. each of those files is using `export default function()`

Comment: Not ES6, but since you're probably using something like webpack or browserify, you can use `require`, which gives you the ability to do just that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import into properties using ES6 module syntax (destructing)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32124640/1048572)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The `import` statement does not have a return value, so it can never be used to assign directly to a variable like that.

Additionally, `import` and `export` must be declared at the top level.

This is not possible with ES6 and likely will stay that way for the foreseeable future (ES2016+).

However, there is a [HTML Module Loader spec](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/#loader-import) being worked on which will allow you to load modules like:

```
System.import('../tasks/renew_creep_life')
.then(renewCreepLife => {

});
```

But since it's promise-based, you'll still not be able to just write it inline in an object like that.

If you want synchronous loading, NodeJS' `require` is probably the closest you'll get. There are browser implementations such as Webpack/Browserify/etc. which attempt to mimic the behaviour:

```
const taskFuncs = {
    [Tasks.RENEW]: require('../tasks/renew_creep_life').default
};
```

Comment: Btw, in my opinion your original solution is explicit, clear, concise and more importantly statically analyzable. I personally would keep what you have.

Comment: It'd have to be `require('../tasks/renew_creep_life').default` then, no?

Comment: @mpen In true CommonJS yes, you're right (some browser implementations aren't 100% compliant - Babel 5 for example) - I'll update